# magento product attribute with wysiwyg, src="{{media url="image.jpg"}} not parsed

Tags: php, html, magento-1.7

Hi I'm working with Magento 1.7

I create a text area attribute with `wysiwyg` allowed and visible on the product page.
when I insert an image I can see only the html text of the attribute, images don’t appear.

If I analyse the generated html code, I can see that the code included by the wysiwyg editor like
`src="{{media url="image.jpg"}}`
has not been parsed.

The code I use is:

```
echo $ _Product-> getData ('technical_support');
```

I tried to print the attribute with

```
echo $this->helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), nl2br($_technical_support), 'technical_support') );
```

But the attribute is not printed

How can I fix it?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how u have to call the images through wysiwyg editor. You have to click show/hide button. Then u can write html tags there. Here is the example

```
<p class="home-callout"><img src="{{skin url='images/ph_callout_left_rebel.jpg'}}" alt=""  /></p>
```

Flower brackets are missing in ur code.

And for attribute, your process is wrong.. Follow this link [Calling an attribute in a CMS block in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710077/calling-an-attribute-in-a-cms-block-in-magento)